# BeautifulSoup - Get all values of an attribute

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've an HTML markup as follow:-

```
<div class="a b c" some-attribute="1">
    <div><div>
</div>

<div class="a b c" some-attribute="2">
    <div><div>
</div>

<div class="a b c" some-attribute="3">
    <div><div>
</div>
```

How do I get the list of all values of `some-attribute`?

I've tried enough, but ain't getting any solution.

This is what I've tried.

Similar to finding all hrefs `[a['href'] for a in soup.find_all('a', href=True)]`, I tried this

```
[div['some-attribute'] for div in soup.find_all('div', some-attribute=True)]  # syntax error
```

Also, I tried:-

```
links = soup.findAll('div', {'class': 'a'})
[link.get('some-attribute') for link in links]
```

This also does not work.

Where am I wrong? or what is the right solution for the above problem?

Comment: What does "does not work" mean? Because at least the last version [works when I try it](https://repl.it/repls/FractalShabbySyndrome).

Comment: And the only reason the first one doesn't work is that `some-attribute` isn't a valid Python identifier. The help explains the two ways to handle that, but since you already used one of those two ways in your next attempt, you should already know that.

Comment: @abarnert - 2 ways. What's the other way?

Comment: Turn that attribute key-value pair into a dict and pass that dict directly, or marge all your attribute key-value pairs (in this case, there's just one) into something you can use with `attrs=…`.

Comment: Meanwhile, have you read [the help](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#kinds-of-filters), or are you trying to guess at the rules by looking at random examples you find online?

Comment: Why not try like this `items = [item.get("some-attribute") for item in soup.find_all(class_=["a","b","c"])]`. there are millions of identical questions in this site.

Answer (score 0):

Use a dict to find all divs: `soup.find_all('div', {"some-attribute" : True})`

```
[x.get_attribute_list('some-attribute') for x in soup.find_all('div', {"some-attribute" : True})]
```

Output:

```
[['1'], ['2'], ['3']]
```

Flatten list or whatever you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `has_attr("some-attribute")` to check if the tag has your attrs.

**Demo:**

```
s = """<div class="a b c" some-attribute="1">
    <div><div>
</div>

<div class="a b c" some-attribute="2">
    <div><div>
</div>

<div class="a b c" some-attribute="3">
    <div><div>
</div>

<div class="a b c">
    <div><div>
</div>"""

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(s, "html.parser")
res = [i.attrs["some-attribute"] for i in soup.find_all("div", class_ = "a b c") if i.has_attr("some-attribute")]
print(res)
```

**Output:**

```
[u'1', u'2', u'3']
```

Answer (score -1):

You can specify the div class to search for:

```
import re
vals = [i['some-attribute'] for i in soup(content, 'html.parser').find_all('div', {'class':re.compile('someclass\d+')})]
```

Output:

```
['1', '2', '3']
```

Comment: What does re.compile do?

Comment: Also, please see the updated question. I've updated values of class attribute.